# Jquery-ajax form submit changes css

Tags: css, jquery, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a ColdFusion page with few div tags. I am doing an Ajax submission to populate result set of mxUnit results to another div.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myURL.cfm",
    data: $dataToPass,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#testResults').html(data);
    }
});
return false;
```

When the result is displayed in my #testResults div, it messes up all of my css from the left column.
Any suggestions on avoiding this.

Comment: what do you mean from the left column?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing a working example or at very least the HTML code (before and after AJAX). The HTML you are inserting is likely breaking your layout.  maybe try to put together a fiddle for the problem.

Comment: there are two divs side by side. Value in a left column is my directory structure containing all my tests and it has some Jquery animation applied to it. So when one of them is clicked, the test is run and result we get back through Ajax submission is displayed in right div. But the whole look and feel of directory div is scrambled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the returned html page.
I checked for the returned html page and rendered it in jsFiddle. It had some of its own CSS which was conflicting with mine.

Thanks for all the comments.